# How to remove child nodes in php

Tags: php, dom

I am using `DOMDocument` class in PHP to remove all the child nodes of 'body' element. My code is as follows

```
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("a.html");

$wrapperDiv=$doc->createElement('div');
$wrapperDiv->setAttribute('class','wrapper');

$body= $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach( $body->childNodes as $child)
{

        if($child->nodeName != "#text")
        {
            $wrapperDiv->appendChild($child);
            $body->removeChild($child);
        }

} 

$body->appendChild($wrapperDiv);
$doc->saveHTMLFile('aaa.html');
```

at `$body->removeChild($child);` it gives me error

> Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\dum2.php:70 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\dum2.php(70):
>   DOMNode->removeChild(Object(DOMElement)) #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\dum2.php on line 70

I have been struggling with this for a long time now but could not figure out what the problem is, as I am new to using this `DOMDocument` class. The 'body' element does contain children!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A node can only have one parent. So I assume that when you called `$wrapperDiv->appendChild($child);`, `$child` is not a child of `$body` anymore and hence `$body->removeChild($child);` throws an error.

Meaning: You don't need to remove the child as it is already removed.

If on the other hand you really want to remove the children and not append them anywhere else, then remove `$wrapperDiv->appendChild($child);`.

**Update:** Indeed it seems that if there are several Element nodes, not all of the nodes are moved: http://codepad.org/8udqSNMj

To fix this, try to iterate over the child elements in reverse order:

```
$children = $body->childNodes;
for($i = $children->length; $i--;) {
    $child = $children->item($i);
    if($child->nodeName != "#text") {
        $wrapperDiv->appendChild($child);
    }
}
```

http://codepad.org/LtuJN2ZT

Comment: I have tried it and its nt working. the child nodes doesn't get removed from the body element...not even when i remove `$wrapperDiv->appendChild($child);` ...

Comment: @Salman: How are you testing whether there are children or not?

Comment: i have edited the code in question. the a.html file contains div and img tags,...

Comment: hmmm...can it be because im using loadHTMLFile instead?

Comment: oh n try putting atleast two childs n then see if it works for u or nt!! cauze i some how get this feeling that if u r iterating over children u r nt allowed to change them.