# How to insert node in hierarchy of DOM between one node and it's child nodes?

Tags: php, dom

I have a DOM looking like this:

```
 div id = main
   div
   div
```

And i want to put the div called "middle" like this:

```
  div id = main
   div id = middle
     div
     div
```

So i want to move all child nodes of main node to the middle node and the middle node to become only child of main. I try to figure it out but i can't.

I use this code:

```
 $wrapper = $doc->createElement('div');
 foreach($node->childNodes as $child) 
 {
     $node->removeChild($child);
     $wrapper->appendChild($child);
 }
 $node->appendChild($wrapper);
```

But it does not work.

And if i do:

```
          $wrapper = $doc->createElement('div');
          $children = $node->childNodes;
          for($i = $children->length; $i--;) {
              $child = $children->item($i);
              $node->removeChild($child);
              $wrapper->appendChild($child);
          } 
           $node->appendChild($wrapper);
```

Items are moved, but in reverse order.

How to do this correctly in PHP?

Comment: Create a new DOM node, iterate over the child nodes of the existing node and add them as children the new node. Then insert the new node as child of the existing node.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code i use according to your commend and it does not work.

Comment: What exactly does "it does not work" mean? Do you get an error? Don't you get the structure you want? Please provide some more information.

Comment: I would xpath the part where you want to insert your node and then use "insertBefore"

Comment: Btw, it seems this question (which I coincidently answered as well), covers your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821164/how-to-remove-child-nodes-in-php

Comment: wrapper div is created at the end of the main div with first child of main div inside and rest of child nodes of main div are still in the same place.

Comment: i've tried the adapted version of the solution from the link you provided but if i use it i have all items in reverse order ....

Comment: Then use `insertBefore`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php

Comment: insertBefore instead of appendChild right?

Comment: thanks, i reversed the order in other way ;) but your idea is better. posted solution below. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          $wrapper = $doc->createElement('div');
          $children = $node->childNodes;
          for($i = 0; $children->length > 0; $i++) {
              $child = $children->item(0);
              $node->removeChild($child);
              $wrapper->appendChild($child);
          } 
           $node->appendChild($wrapper);
```